# How do I access my webservice on port 443 using https?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-service, ports, port-forwarding

I am trying to run a webservice via https on port 443 via self-signed certificate. Here is what I did first:

- Forwarded port 8080
- Create self-signed certificate with openssl
- Add certificate to trusted root using certlm
- ran the webservice via https on port 8080
- access `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`, where the x's are my public ip address

This worked perfectly. Now I want it to work for port 443 instead.

- Forward port 443 (HTTPS)
- re-run webservice on port 443 this time
- access `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443`

But this just brings me to my router login page. How can I get this to route to my webservice on port 443? Am I missing something about how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Your router probably doesn't support forwarding `443` because it collides with the web interface. (Note that this is not a security question, so it's off-topic here.)

Comment: Your router is a piece of crap that can't prevent itself from hijacking your port 443. There's also a good chance the web interface it serves on there is vulnerable and/or has a backdoor. I suggest you throw it away and replace it with a decent SoHo/enterprise router (Ubiquiti are my personal favorites, but Cisco will do as well).